# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected & Invalid token 'else' in class record

Tags: c#

I have an error that I cannot figure out.
I have just put some text here, please guide.

Here's the error:

> Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

> Invalid token 'else' in class record, struct, or interface member declaration

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IMS
{
    public partial class Login : BaseForm
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Usernametxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Usernametxt.Text=="") {usernameError.Visible = true;}else{ usernameError.Visible = false; }
        }

        private void Passtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Passtxt.Text == ""){passError.Visible = true;}else { passError.Visible = false;}
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Usernametxt.Text == "" && Passtxt.Text == "")
            {
                if (Usernametxt.Text == "") {usernameError.Visible = true; }else{usernameError.Visible = false;}
                if (Passtxt.Text == ""){passError.Visible = true;}else{ passError.Visible = false;}
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All these `if` statements you have crammed on one line can be reduced, for example: `usernameError.Visible = Usernametxt.Text=="";`  The equality test's result *is* the boolean value you want to assign.

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine. Where does the compiler tell you these errors are happening?

Comment: on last line where last curly close, and in last else, code was working fine but when i start this [ private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) ] error appear at time of compiling

Comment: Edit the question, puting a comment on the code where you're trying to add the method. Looks like you're either writing a method outside the class or inside a method.

Comment: thanks for support, problem solved, event define without method & spell error in class.. and thanks @madreflection for great suggestion .